# how Petrov-Galerkin FEM different from others and advantages

Tags: finite-element

How is the Petrov-Galerkin FEM different from more common FEMs? Could anyone give a layman description? What's the advantages of using the Petrov-Galerkin FEM?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the Galerkin (=FEM) and Petrov-Galerkin methods is that in the former test and trial functions are the same, whereas in the latter they are not.

Comment: thanks a lot. What's the advantages of using the Petrov-Galerkin FEM?

Comment: Well, I think that's debatable. There are certainly cases where it *is* useful, whereas in others one could ask why it was necessary to propose a method that uses Petrov-Galerkin approaches when there are already plenty of good methods around. I think the best example of the former would be Streamline Upwind Petrov-Galerkin (SUPG). You might want to read up on that.

Comment: very helpful thanks. matlab has a pdepe solver solving parabolic and elliptic PDEs, which is based on Petrov-Galerkin. If SUPG is designed to solve convection dominated ones, why would matlab use this algorithm for solving non-hyperbolic ones?

Comment: I would have no idea!